# CSS Negate: Displaying specific elements in a hidden Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume we have an element that is similar to this

```
<div id="navigation">
   <div class="nav-block-1">....</div>
   <div class="nav-block-2">....</div>
   This is the offer
   <a href="#"> Report </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to hide all the elements including the textelements but not the `nav-block-2`, so is there a way through which I can do this? Something like using CSS negation?

I tried using

```
#navigation :not(.nav-block-2) {
   display:none;
}
```

but this seems to negating even the elements inside nav-block-2? Am I doing something wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: `#navigation:not(.nav-block-2)` will select elements with `id=navigation` and `class!=nav-block-2`. You need a space between the two to denote children.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, it was intended to like this before, this is still not solving my issues.

Comment: Now you are not specifying that you don't want the children of nav-block-2 to be hidden, only the element itself.

Comment: hey man just give wrap `This is the offer` in any HTML tag like `<span>This is the offer</span`.... else you will need a big code of js!

Comment: As far as I know, `display:none;` is inherited over all sub nodes and overwriting display in a sub node will not have any effect.

Comment: @Jivings exactly! but how do I do that?

Comment: @AspiringAqib I don't have control on the HTML in this case.

Comment: @SrikanthRayabhagi After experimenting I don't think you can do what you want in CSS alone. You don't seem to be able to not select the children in a negation.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not what you want but here's what i'd do.

```
#navigation * {
    display:none;
}
#navigation a {
    display:inline;
}
```

EDIT:
As it says in the comments in your question, I think it's difficult to do a :not when there's no tag around the text.

Comment: This will make the anchor inline, along with text. To test `#navigation * {
  display: none;
}` itself leaves the text behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#navigation div:not(.nav-block-2) {
   display:none;
}


<div id="navigation">
   <div class="nav-block-1">Div 1</div>
   <div class="nav-block-2">Div 2</div>
    This is the offer
   <a href="#"> Report </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```css
#navigation > *:not(.nav-block-2) {
   display:none;
}
```

However, you can't hide single text nodes. You will need to put the "This is the offer" in a paragraph or at least in a `<span>` tag to hide it, or you would need to hide the whole `#navigation` which inevitable contains the `.nav-block-2`.